# How to generate documentation like Stripe API

Tags: java, spring, api, stripe-payments, documentation

I have a Sprint boot based Java server that exposes REST endpoints. I need to create documentation for external customers on the endpoints. I'm not a fan of the Swagger generated docs. I'd like to be able to generate documentation like the Stripe API's : https://stripe.com/docs/api

Do you know what tool can be used to generate Stripe API like documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe apparently uses a tool they built called [Markdoc](https://markdoc.dev/) for their documentation. There's [a blog post on Stripe's website](https://stripe.com/blog/markdoc) about how they built it, and Markdoc is available to the public.

There are other automated API documentation tools available, too. [Swagger](https://swagger.io/solutions/api-documentation/) is one example, and [Postman](https://www.postman.com/api-documentation-tool/) is another.

Comment: Are there any open source projects that have source of Markdoc for their API's published? Like the frames and style of the Stripe API. I'd like to see a full fledged example. The examples of Markdoc I see are simple syntax sandboxes

Answer (score 1):

use slate, its inspired to Stripe and paypal

https://github.com/slatedocs/slate